# What is the name of this piece and where can I find a UL listed part

Tags: lighting, repair, lamp

What is the name of this piece and where can I find a UL listed replacement part.

[image]

Comment: That cRUus logo there is as UL-listish as you're going to get. It means "UL **Recognized** (Canada) (US)" meaning it's a pre-approved component, and will hasten UL listing of a fixture containing it.

Comment: why are you not saying what the *piece* is? ... it looks like a light socket component, but it is impossible to determine its size ... downvote for not providing all available information

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Lighting socket? Is this the side of the socket that the lamp or heating element inserts into? If you can break down the socket configuration from the bulb used you might find the socket by the configuration. Kind of looks like it could  a G22 socket (22 mm pin separation).

Answer (score 1):

That looks just like the terminal fitting for a lamp or bulb holder. Too cheap to be available separately.

I would suggest it is easier to purchase a complete unit especially as some parts may have been changed over time.

Answer (score 1):

The NEC rules requiring UL ([or equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory)) only apply to *equipment* such as a junction box or light fixture.

This is not equipment.  This is *a component of* equipment.

You are attempting subunit repair of what looks like a light fixture. This isn't the whole fixture, just a *component*, looks like a socket.

Suppose Joe manufactures  light fixtures and seeks a UL *Listing*.  Joe *buys* the lampholders, does not make them in-house. UL tears down the unit and torture-tests every part, including those lampholders.  Also. UL does ongoing inspection of Joe's factory to assure actual output resembles the test articles. *Including the lampholder factory*  - on Joe's dime!

Well, some manufacturers of lampholders had UL *pre-approve* their components. That is the "RU" stamp you see on this piece.  It's called "*ЯU*-Recognized" because it's for components, not equipment.  Anyway, by smartly choosing *ЯU*-Recognized lampholders, Joe breezed through UL listing, and doesn't have to pay to inspect the lampholder or its factory.

So all you need to do is use an *ЯU*-Recognized replacement, and you're good to go.